# What serializer to use with Akka Cluster

Tags: akka-cluster

Not much info about it online.
Java Serializer is not good (performance, schema evolution). 
Kyro is a good option (that's what we use), but both of the libraries have not been updated in a while ([romix](https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization), [chill](https://github.com/twitter/chill)), and don't support schema evolution out of the box
Lagom uses Json, which is fine, but a binary format seems more appropriate .

For our use case, simplicity of use is the most important. Follow by performance and schema evolution (nice to have, but we can always do a cluster restart with very minimal downtime)

Answer (score 0):

Jackson cbor is supported out-of-the-box these days : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization.html

We're very content with performance and data size in general. No schema evolution however.